# Imported SSL certificate not showing up in CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager, amazon-cloudfront

[image: AWS Certificate Manager]

[image: Cloudfront. In the dropdown it is showing for different certificate for other domain not for the one I have added certificate for.]

Already made sure certificate is on N.Virginia region. 
Also tried typing out the domain name giving this error:

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value '*.domainname.com ' at 'serverCertificateId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 32 (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400;
```

Still can't figure out the exact problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFront supports public key length of 1024 and 2048 bits.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html

The ACM certificate you have uploaded is of 4096 bit and isn't supported by CloudFront.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that.